# Changed git repository name on bitbucket and now authentication fails when I try pull/push

Tags: git, bitbucket

When I try to pull it hangs for a while, then the error I'm getting is: `fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://...'`
I've looked at a couple of answers, but they don't work for me.
I'm using ssh keys for login.
When I run `git remote -v` it returns the correct urls for push/pull, my git config looks good.
What am I missing?
I've seen things like this suggested a few times:
`git config --global credential.helper store`
But they don't work, I assume because I'm not using a user/password in that way.
Got any ideas?
EDIT: More info -
After changing the url to `ssh` I get the following:

```
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.apps.mysite.com (10.101.10.10)' can't 
be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:2EAIgH1GS8Ocfepmi/hjhEu8paYcohl53kuVm9GgxRU.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.apps.mysite.com,10.101.10.10' (ECDSA) 
to the list of known hosts.
myuser@bitbucket.apps.mysite.com: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi- 
keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

So at least it's a step in the right direction.

Comment: You have re-cloned the reposity when you have changed the name of the reposity?

Comment: `When I run git remote -v it returns the correct urls for push/pull` What are the correct urls? `I'm using ssh keys for login.` You can't use ssh keys for https.

Comment: What is the remote url like now? Does it start with `http` or `ssh` or `username@host`?

Comment: @tkausl I think that's it. the url should be ssh

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo I can't do that as I have a couple of local feature branches that haven't been merged. I should have pushed those before I made the changes, but I didn't

Comment: @vincenzopalazzo it starts with `ssh`

Comment: @ElpieKay it starts with 'ssh' getting a new error now

Comment: @tkausl more info added, new error.

Comment: @bo_bot I had an similar problem with bitbuket and I must re-recloning the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the url suggested by the site was wrong. Our bitbucket is hosted on our own domain. 
The website suggested changing the clone url to:

```
https://bitbucket.apps.mysite.com/scm/op/my-service.git
```

But I should have been using the `ssh` url like this:

```
ssh://git@bitbucket.apps.mysite.com:7999/op/my-service.git
```